# User multiple input

Tags: java, eclipse

So, the task is "User inputs 10 numbers, count how many are odd or even", I started with just writing how to decide which is odd/even and now my brain is actually dead and I can't find almost any help online. 
P.S. Just a 1st year student starting with java

```
 public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int x;
      System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      x = in.nextInt();

      if (x % 2 == 0)
         System.out.println("The number is even.");
      else
         System.out.println("The number is odd.");
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks already good. Only one (e. g. `for`) loop is missing around it, which executes it 10x times and also the code for the counting has to be written.

Comment: @howlger thank you for the reply, but I believe I have written the question wrong, the idea was that the user inputs 100 numbers at once ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ) and the programm counts the odd/even numbers. And the problem I have, is that I don't know how to allow 10 differnt variables? I believe

Comment: I see. With `String line = in.nextLine();` you can read a whole line, `for (String number : line.split("\\s++")) { ... }` iterates of each whitespace separated token and `int x = Integer.parseInt(number);` converts the String token to an `int`.

Comment: @howlger hmm, thank you, I kinda don't understand where should i put the for cycle

Comment: The `for`-each-loop must be after reading the line and the conversions from String to `int` must be inside the loop as it has to be done for every number. As soon this works, you can replace the output of even or odd with counting. But as a first step, try to read a line and do an output for each number.